# Regex separating string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this test string I want to separate it in 2 variables first is username and second is phone_number I tried using regex but it doesn't work.

```
var test = "Olu Odunsi  [+447963595685]";
```

Output Expected

```
var name= Olu Odunsi;
var phon_number= +447963595685;
```

My code

```
var test = test.match(/[A-Z](.*)]/);
```

Comment: What regex doesn't work? Please post it and explain what the problem is with the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
var test = "Olu Odunsi  [+447963595685]";
var res=test.replace("]","").split(/\s+\[/);
console.log(res);
```